# Replace and extract matches with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

How can I get all matches with for example preg_match_all() and also replace the results with an empty string?

I've tried stuff like this:

```
<?php
$comments   = array();              

$selectors  = preg_replace_callback('~\*(?>(?:(?>([^*]+))|\*(?!\/))*)\*~',
function ($match) {
    $comments[] = $match[0];
    return '';
}, $input);
?>
```

But that doesn't work very well since the $comment variable doesn't seem to be accessable from the anonymous function.
I guess I can make global variables, but I really don't want to mess up the namespace like that

Comment: why not just use preg_replace ?

Comment: Because then I can't get/extract all the matches (that was replaced). Or is that possible?

Comment: Try `use` in the function declaration: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
$comments   = array();              

$selectors  = preg_replace_callback('~\*(?>(?:(?>([^*]+))|\*(?!\/))*)\*~',
function ($match) use (&$comments) {  //add the variable $comments to the function scope
    $comments[] = $match[0];
    return '';
}, $input);
?>
```